# Симпсон парадокс в Stack Overflow данных

Tags: обсуждение, цифры

Глядя на все ~10 миллионов Stack Exchange вопросов, вероятность что ответ будет принят увеличивается (слегка) для последних ответов в сессии для участника (сессия -- ~ответы участника за один присест/за день):

[image: aggregated data]

Если посмотреть на те же данные разделённые по длине сессии (сколько ответов за раз участник пишет). То противоположная тенденция: более поздние ответы с меньшей вероятностью принимаются:

[image: disaggregated data]

В этом и состоит 
[парадокс Симпсона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0): объединённые данные из нескольких групп показывают один тренд, когда данные для каждой группы по отдельности показывают противоположную зависимость.

Из статьи: [Can you trust the trend? Discovering Simpson’s paradoxes in social data](https://blog.acolyer.org/2018/02/21/can-you-trust-the-trend-discovering-simpsons-paradoxes-in-social-data/)

---

Определение что такое "сессия" из [оригинальной статьи](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04385.pdf):

> User actions, i.e., answering questions,
>   can be segmented into sessions—periods of activity without a
>   prolonged break. Following [9] we use 100 minutes as minimum
>   break length to define sessions. A time interval longer than 100
>   minutes between two answers constitutes the end of one session
>   and the start of a new one.

Сессия -- период активности без долгого перерыва. В статье, перерыв больше 100 минут означает конец сессии.

> Note that the exact value of this threshold
>   does not change results, but simply merge a small fraction of
>   sessions into longer sessions.

Результаты (демонстрация парадокса Симпсона) не зависят от точной длины перерыва.

Comment: Разочарован, что это не тот Симпсон.

Comment: Что-то я не понял, что измерялось...

Comment: @Qwertiy: какая ось не ясна: "вероятность, что ответ будет принят" или что такое позиция ответа в сессии (первый ответ за день, второй ответ за день, третий ответ за день итд). Цвета представляют длину сессии: синий -- два ответа за сессию, красный -- восемь.

Comment: Т. е. сессия = день по UTC? А в практический смысл именно такого критерия?

Comment: @Qwertiy нет. См. определение сессии в вопросе.

Comment: Смотрю: _"сессия -- ~ответы участника за один присест/за день"_ - не понимаю.

Comment: до конца дочитайте.

Comment: Еще одно наблюдение -- чем длиннее серия, тем выше  вероятность принятых ответов. А внутри серии одного размера все же вероятность быть принятым выше у первых ответов.

Comment: Ну собственно логично, чем дольше времени проходит после задания вопроса тем неинтереснее становится вопрос для того кто спрашивал, т.к. он мог найти сам ответ, либо встретить тот что его устроил либо просто вопрос мог стать не актуальным. Следовательно, поздние ответы и привлекают мало внимания => принимаются меньше

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov это не разные ответы к одному и тому же вопросу, это ответы одного и того же человека к [разным] вопросам. Вот вы зашли на сайт и опубликовали несколько ответов с перерывами между ними не больше 100 минут. У более позднего вашего ответа в сессии будет меньше шансов принятым быть.

Comment: @jfs тогда это очень любопытная корреляция, видимо сказывается интузиазм и интелектуальное истощение отвечающего на качество его ответов))

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov вероятность уменьшается в течении сессии, если сравнивать сессии одинаковой длины (второй график). Но общая тенденция противоположная—ответ с большим номером в сессии более вероятно принятым быть (первый график).